# How to extract information from dll compiled in gcc with debug symbols?

Tags: decompilation, debuggers, dll, debugging, compilers

I recently read that GCC annotates the source-code into the debug symbols it produces, although I haven't found any examples on how to retrieve this.

If this is true, how can I view the data in the debug symbols, mainly the code annotations.

What would be the steps I need to complete starting with a gcc compiled dll with debug symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either [readelf](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/readelf.html) utility with -w (or --debug-dump) command line switch or [nm](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) utility with -a command line switch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been testing readelf, is there any way how to save the data into a file so I can actually view the the output?

Comment: output redirection. Example: readelf -w {your binary name} >> required.log.file.name